# Is it common practice to use jQuery in MRAID Ads (mobile only)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqlite, mraid

Is it common practice to use JavaScript libraries in an [MRAID Ad](http://www.iab.net/MRAID)?

I'm looking to implement a magazine-style “page-turning” user interface for an MRAID Ad on mobile only.

I can see from the documentation that jQuery is mentioned, however I'm not sure if this would be too heavy to load, worth calling a CDN (it'd probably be cached):

> **Using 3rd party library bindings without using their ready event method** Third party libraries such as jQuery have a ready method
>   which help facilitate a similar functionality as the mraid ready event
>   listener. In the example of jQuery, putting the DOM click bindings
>   inside of the ready(handler) method makes sure that the entire page
>   has finished loading before starting execution of any other jQuery
>   functions.

Comment: If you can run Javascript, you can also run Javascript that other people wrote, including jQuery.

Comment: I guess I might be concerned with the load speed of a heavy library?

Comment: Then what is your question?

Comment: Is it a common practice to use jQuery or other libraries? If so would it best to include all the source code inline? Is it performant enough?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use jQuery, but if you want to manipulate the DOM, you have to check if the document is ready and also if mraid is ready. From the same document:

> Binding your initialization to just the `window.ready` event ignores that the MRAID libraries may not be available yet. Likewise, listening only for `mraid.ready` event ignores that the HTML DOM may still be rendering. Be sure to check for both ready states - and maybe even `isViewable` - before triggering initialization routines.